# Проблемы с callback в `QWebEnginePage().runJavaScript(js_code, callback)`

Tags: python, сигналы-слоты, pyqt6, qwebengineview, runjavascript

В настоящее время я изучаю *PyQt6* и мне интересно узнать больше о возможностях `QtWebEngine`. 
Буду признателен, если вы порекомендуете какие-нибудь руководства или учебные пособия по изучению `QtWebEngine`.
Заранее спасибо за вашу помощь.

Я понимаю, что проблема заключается в том, что тег `img` не появляется на веб-странице вовремя, чтобы метод `JavaScript findElementByClassName` мог его найти.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl


def js_handle_callback(result):
    print('Result: ', type(result), result)

js_code = """
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('lnXdpd');
canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
var base64String = canvas.toDataURL();
base64String;
"""

def js_run():
    page.runJavaScript(js_code, js_handle_callback)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QWebEngineView()
    page = view.page()
    page.loadFinished.connect(js_run)
    view.load(QUrl('https://google.com'))
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

**Output**:

```
Result:  <class 'NoneType'> None
```

Пробовал использовать сигнал `loadFinished`, но не помогает. 
*JavaScript* `window.addEventListener('load', function(){ My Code })` также не помогает, поскольку `callback` не ожидает события `'load'`.

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю с чего вы решили, что:

> ... что проблема заключается в том, что тег `img` не появляется
> на веб-странице вовремя,
> чтобы метод `JavaScript findElementByClassName` мог его найти.

Я не знаю, что должен делать `js_code = """ ... """`

А вот сигнал `loadFinished` - работает как надо, проверьте.

```
import sys
''' 
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication                             # PyQt6
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl
'''
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication                             # PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, pyqtSlot                              # + pyqtSlot


def js_handle_callback(result):                     # не использовал
    print(f'\n Result: {type(result)}; {result}\n') # не использовал

# не использовал
# Sorry, я не не знаю что тут и     'canvas' - это что такое ??? <------- ???
js_code = """                        vvvvvv  <------------- это что такое ???
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('lnXdpd');
canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
var base64String = canvas.toDataURL();
base64String;
"""

def callback_function(html):                                         # +++
    print('-= callback_function(html): START =-' * 2)
    print(f'\n{html[:300]}\n\n ... \n\n{html[-300:]}\n')
    print('-= callback_function(html): END =-' * 3)

@pyqtSlot(bool)                                                      # +++
def js_run(finished):

    print(f'\ndef js_run(): 111 {finished} <<===== \n    load finished {finished} <<=====') #
    page = view.page()                                               # +++
    
    print(f'def js_run(): 222  {page} \n\t{view.url()}') #
        
#    page.runJavaScript(js_code, js_handle_callback)                 # ??? js_code

    page.runJavaScript(                                              # +++     
        "document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML",        # +++
        callback_function                                            # +++
)                                                                    # +++
    print(f'def js_run(): 333 inject js ok\n') #
    
def onLoadStarted():
    print('\nload started: ожидание завершения загрузки страницы)')
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QWebEngineView()
#    page = view.page()

    view.loadStarted.connect(onLoadStarted)                          # +++
    view.loadFinished.connect(js_run)                                # +++  
#    page.loadFinished.connect(js_run)
    
    view.load(QUrl('https://google.com'))
    print(f'\n111 {view}\n') #
    
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Pibjoy9m что не так?